# Internal IIS web site to URL

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8

I have installed a web site on one of my servers within our active directory domain. How do I create an actual URL such as http://TheWebApp instead of having users navigate to http://192.168.0.xxx/TheWebApp?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: 1) You need some help on DNS to map `TheWebApp` to `192.168.0.xxx`. 2) You also need some help to rewrite `http://TheWebApp` to `http://TheWebApp/TheWebApp` (or simply change your web server site configuration to remove the `/TheWebApp` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 192.168.0.xx and WebApp to hosts file in local machine. Then set the application as an independent site on server and bind to localhost:80. When you enter the `http://WebApp` in local machine, it will forwards to `http://192.168.0.xx` and points to the site on server.

Or you can buy a public domain and bind it to your server, then bind site to domain.

Comment: That would mean that I would have to edit the hosts file on all machines on my network? Buy a public domain for strictly an Intranet site? This is for internal, within the domain usage only and never accessible from the outside.

Comment: Yes, I know it may be trouble but it is most simplest. Or you can set a DNS server in Internal and set each machines' DNS to this server. DNS will forward request to 192.168.0.xxx server.